# Homebrew - OpenNLP installing to hidden folder

Tags: homebrew, catalina

I used this command to install OpenNLP and it installed to a hidden Library folder (Users/me/(hidden)Library/Caches/Homebrew).

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

Is that possibly due to having just upgraded to Catalina? And, how can I change it to being in a non-hidden folder?

Comment: `STRING='ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null'`; `echo $STRING | grep opennlp`; ***nada, niente, nüscht!*** Please consider to revise your question or at least the content of the command as it is posted here currently.

Comment: I'm sorry - but what is wrong with the content of the command that I posted? I can see that you edited it and so I should have put it in the code block like you made it. Is that all?

Comment: The `ruby -e "$(curl ... )"` command installs homebrew (a package manager). The redirects are questionable. You can use homebrew to install apache-opennlp: `brew install apache-opennlp`. This installs apache-opennlp to /usr/local/.... With the command given in your question you can't install opennlp. Thus we won't be able to tell you what went wrong.

Comment: Or with other words: /Users/$USER/Library/Caches/Homebrew is a common folder used by `brew` to cache brew related downloads/files. Depending on your user folder view settings the Library folder is visible or invisible. The Library folder itself is a standard user folder folder (like Desktop, Music etc.).

Comment: Thank you for explaining. My problem is that the user library folder is automatically hidden by mac. I tried un-hiding it with: chflags nohidden ~/Library/ but it didn't work. So, when I'm in Eclipse, I cannot access my ~/Library/ folder to import files from there. Is there another way to permanently un-hide the ~/Library/ folder?

Comment: As commented: opennlp should have been installed to /usr/local/... (I think it's ./opt but I may check it once more). The ~/Library/Caches/Homebrew folder shouldn't be accessed by Eclipse because it doesn't contain anything useful (except cached brew data). Would you mind searching for the relevant part sof your Terminal history (probably: `cat ~/.zsh_history`) and adding everything brew/opennlp related to your question? Please edit out anything personal/password related before psoting it here.

Comment: It's a link pointing to a folder (/usr/local/opt/apache-opennlp) and and link pointing to a binary (/usr/local/bin/opennlp). The originals both reside deep in /usr/local/Cellar/apache-opennlp/1.9.1/...

Comment: To make your Library folder visible open your user folder: cmd-shift-H and hit: cmd-J to get the view options. Then toggle the last radio button: "Show Library folder".

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I don't have the "Show Library folder". I can see it, because I'm showing all my hidden folders at the moment. For me, it's about being able to configure the build path and add external .jar files from the opennlp package. But in Eclipse I cannot do that because the ~/Library/ is hidden.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a tutorial/how-to (or similar), then I will  set it up here and write an answer. I found this one: [OpenNLP - Environment](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/opennlp/opennlp_environment.htm) - apparently old and for WIndows.